# Serverless function hangs with sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, serverless

When I am using sequelize with serverless the endpoint will take a long time to respond due to the sequelize connection pool.

I have defined sequelize like the following:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */, {
  // ...
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

Now when I access any of my endpoints they will take as long as the idle amount that is set on my sequelize.

e.g. idle: 10000 - endpoints take about 10 seconds to respond.

How do I fix this issue? Is there a way to respond with the serverless function without waiting for the idle time to complete?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried decreasing the idle value? According to [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor), 10000 ms is the default value.